# AES CBC MAC Generation

Tags: aes, mac

I am working with Atmel's/MicroChip's ATAES132A 32K AES Serial EEPROM chip for hardware encryption and decryption. This is my first venture into cryptography. I've been reading through the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATAES132A-Data-Sheet-40002023A.pdf) and have a question on how to generate the MAC for decryption. I've asked this question on the Atmel forum, but I didn't get any responses. I figured this is more of a cryptography question rather than a technical one.

Per the datasheet:

> **I.3 MAC Generation**
>
> The following example shows how the integrity MAC is calculated for an
>   authentication operation requiring up to 14 bytes of authenticate-only
>   data. This operation involves three passes through the AES crypto
>   engine; all three using the same key. If there are more than 14 bytes
>   of authenticate-only data, then another pass through the AES crypto
>   engine is required. There are two passes through the AES crypto engine
>   in CBC mode to create the cleartext MAC. The inputs to the crypto
>   engine for those blocks are labeled B0 and B1, and the outputs are B’0
>   and B’1, respectively.
>
> • B0 is composed of the following 128 bits:
>
> – 1 byte flag, a fixed value of b0111 1001. – 12 byte Nonce, as
>   generated by the Nonce command. – 1 byte MacCount, one for first MAC
>   generation. – 2 byte length field, always 0x00 00 for authentication
>   only.
>
> • B1 is the XOR of B’0 with the following 128 bits: – 2 byte length
>   field, size of authenticate-only data. – 14 byte data to be
>   authenticated only.
>
> • B’1 is the cleartext MAC, which must be encrypted before being sent
>   to the system.
>
> There is one additional pass through the AES crypto engine in CTR mode
>   to create the key block that is used to encrypt the MAC. The input to
>   the crypto engine for this block is labeled A0 and the output is A’0.
>   A’0 is the MAC sent to the system as the output parameter of the Auth
>   command.
>
> • A0 is composed of the following 128 bits: – 1 byte flag – fixed
>   value of b0000 0001. – 12 byte Nonce – as generated by ATAES132A
>   during Nonce command. – 1 byte MacCount – one for first MAC
>   generation. – 2 byte counter field – always 0x00 00 for A0.
>
> • A’0 is XOR’d with the cleartext MAC (B’1) and sent to the system.
>
> Input integrity MACs for Auth, Counter, KeyCreate, and Lock are also
>   calculated using this procedure. If the input MAC does not match A’0,
>   then the command returns an AUTH error.

So my question is, in suede-code, are my steps correct?

`B'0` = `B0` XOR with the secret `Key`

`B'1` = `B1` XOR with `B'0`

`A'0` = `B'1` XOR with `A0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are reading is a *description* of how CCM is performed *within the "Cryptographic Element Device*. The block names are [from the CCM description by NIST](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38c.pdf).

A more clear description is the following:

```
N = Nonce(12)

# this implements CBC(key, IV, 79 | NONCE | 01 | 00 00 | LL LL | DATA)
# taking only the last block (AES / CBC-MAC)

IV = 00000000000000000000000000000000 # presumed, it's logical

B0 = 79 | NONCE | 01 | 00 00
B'0 = CBC(key, IV, B0)

B1 = XOR(B'0, LL LL | DATA)
B'1 = CBC(key, IV, B1)

N2 = Nonce(12) # it may be that N2 should be identical to N1, look into spec

# this implements CTR(key, A0, B'1)

A0 = 01 | N | 01 | 0000 # this is the initial counter for CTR mode
A'0 = CTR(key, A0, 00000000000000000000000000000000)
R = XOR(A'0, B'1)
```

This is a *block by block* description on how CCM mode is performed *internally* when up to 14 bytes of data are just MAC'ed - not encrypted. You could use it to mimic the implementation if you're just given AES-CBC and AES-CTR or indeed just AES. On a normal computer you'd just use an existing library that contains CCM.

Comment: Note that I didn't have time to browse through the datasheet. Better test.

Comment: This makes more sense now. However, how do I calculate `CBC(key, IV, B0)`? Forgive my ignorance; `CBC` and `CTR` are functions?

Comment: Yes, they are shorthand for AES in CBC mode or CTR mode. What you are reading is a *description* of how CCM is performed *within the "Cryptographic Element Device*. I'll put that sentence in my answer as well.